# How can I add an html 'path' (tag) from BeautifulSoup as a class instance variable in python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to process html data pulled from websites online. I've created a class 'Websites', with a couple of functions that parse the html scripts based on instance variables like header, class, etc. for my target bit of text. e.g.

```
class Websites:

    def __init__(self, url, header, class_):
        self.url = url
        self.header = header
        self.class_ = class_

    def html(self):
        url = self.url
        webpage = urlopen(url)
        page_html = webpage.read()
        webpage.close()
        page_soup = bs(page_html, 'html.parser')
        return page_soup
```

It's been simple to convert those variables (header, class) to instance variables in the class, but there is one variable that I'm struggling to convert into a class instance variable. I believe in BeautifulSoup lingo it's referred to as the 'tag'. If I call the html function shown above on an instance of the class, I get a block of html text I can save as a variable (page_soup), to which I can add a tag, e.g. like this:

```
page_soup.div.h1.p
```

This specifies the exact part of the html script that I want to access. Is there any way I could modify the class **init** function displayed above so that it could take an input, e.g.:

```
amazon = Websites(url = 'Amazon.co.uk', tag = '.div.h1.p')
```

and use it as an instance variable in a class method, as self.tag?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a tag in that way is the same as using BeautifulSoup's `find()` function, which returns the first matching tag. So you could write your own function to emulate this approach as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_tag(tag, text_attr):
    for attr in text_attr.split('.'):
        if attr:
            tag = tag.find(attr)

    return tag


html = """<html><h2>test1</h2><div><h1>test2<p>display this</p></h1></div></html>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(soup.div.h1.p)
print(get_tag(soup, '.div.h1.p'))
```

This would display:

```html
<p>display this</p>
<p>display this</p>
```

An alternative approach would be to use the [`.select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) function, which returns a list of matching tags:

```
print(soup.select('div > h1 > p')[0])
```